# firebaseHostingへデプロイしたアプリから、firebaseFunctionへリクエストを送り、apiを利用したいです。

Tags: typescript, firebase, express.js, ionic2

### 自分で試したこと

クライアントサイドurl、サーバーサイドのルーティングをいろいろ変えてみましたが駄目でした。
ローカルで実行したときには問題なく動いていたんですが、index.tsを追加して実際にデプロイするとエラーになってしまいました。

### 発生している問題・エラー

```
polyfills.ea3cb635cad86c66.js:1     
POST https://us-central1-musictomovie-af3d1.cloudfunctions.net/api/hello 404
z @ polyfills.ea3cb635cad86c66.js:1
・
・
・
6260.eeadfbd059add584.js:1 POSTリクエストが失敗しました。 Lt {headers: ee, status: 404, statusText: 'OK', url: 'https://us-central1-musictomovie-af3d1.cloudfunctions.net/api/hello', ok: false, …}
```

### 該当するソースコード

#### クライアントサイド

```
  // postリクエストのテスト用
  sendPostRequest() {

    const formData = {
      audio: this.audioFile,
      image: this.imageFile,
    };

    this.http.post<any>('https://us-central1-musictomovie-af3d1.cloudfunctions.net/api/hello',formData).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.response = data.message;
        console.log('サーバーからの応答:', data); // コンソールにも表示（確認用）
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('POSTリクエストが失敗しました。', error);
      }
    );
  }
```

#### サーバーサイド

```
// index.ts:
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import app from "./app";

// Express アプリケーションを Firebase Functions にラップします
const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);

// Firebase Functions のエントリーポイントとしてエクスポートします
export { api };
```

```
// app.ts:
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import mediaRoutes from './routes/media.routes';
import helloRoutes from './routes/hello.routes';


const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// CORS設定（手動で設定）
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['https://us-central1-musictomovie-af3d1.cloudfunctions.net',
    'https://us-central1-musictomovie-af3d1.cloudfunctions.net/api/',
    'https://us-central1-musictomovie-af3d1.cloudfunctions.net/api/hello',
    'https://musictomovie-af3d1.web.app'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'Accept'],
  }));


// エンドポイントのルーティング
app.use('/api', mediaRoutes);
app.use('/api', helloRoutes);

// テスト用のログを追加
console.log("mediaRoutesのルーティングは以下のパスで設定されています:");
console.log("/api/media/createVideo");
console.log("/api/hello");

// app.listen(PORT, () => {
//   console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
// });

export default app;
```

```
// hello.routes.ts:
import express, { Router, Request, Response } from 'express';

const router: Router = express.Router();

console.log("hello.routes.tsが呼び出されました")

// "hello world"をクライアントに返すエンドポイント（POSTリクエスト）
router.post('/hello', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
try {
console.log("hello worldを返します")
res.json({ message: 'hello world' }); // JSON形式で応答を返す
} catch (error) {
console.error("エラーが発生しました:", error);
res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
}
});

export default router;
```